# Differential miRNA expression using RPM

Tags: r, differential-expression, deseq2, gene-expression, edger

I have microRNA (miRNA) expression data in RPM. I would like to do differential gene expression between two groups.

How can I do this?

I have considered edgeR and DESeq2 in R, but it looks like they require counts and I cannot use RPM in these. Or can I convert RPM to counts?

Can anyone help?

Comment: This has been asked many times before. Here is an answer from the edgeR/limma author. Approach 2 in the toplevel question is probably the best choice here if you don't have counts: https://support.bioconductor.org/p/125144/#125156 so an analysis with limma starting from the RPMs on log scale.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.